# ¿Cómo designamos a la acción de tender la ropa que hemos sacado limpia de la lavadora?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, español-neutral, solicitud-de-modismo

Cuando uno tiene ropa sucia, la pone en la lavadora. Pasado el rato, cuando está limpia pero mojada, uno la saca de la máquina y la tiende.

En mi casa denominamos este paso *tender la lavadora*. Es claro el significado, pero literalmente querría decir que elevamos la máquina (que pesa lo suyo), y la suspendemos con unas pinzas. Irreal, vaya.

Me pregunto pues si existe algún tipo de palabra o expresión que quiera decir esto mismo y que se pueda utilizar tanto en España como en Hispanoamérica.

El DLE habla de [*colada*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9jD2Ahi%7C9jHF3Yj) como:

> 1. f. Acción y efecto de colar<sup>2</sup>.
> 2. f. Lejía en que se cuela la ropa.
> 3. f. Ropa colada.
> 4. f. Lavado de ropa sucia de una casa.
> 5. f. Ropa lavada.

de ahí que se diga *hacer la colada* al acto de lavar la ropa. Siguiendo esta línea de pensamiento, parece que ***tender la colada*** podría ser la solución, pero la verdad es que nunca lo he oído.

Comment: En México se tiende la ropa, y no importa cómo se lavó.

Comment: En Argentina "colada" no se usa.

Comment: @leonbloy ¿y tenéis alguna otra palabra para definir este concepto?

Comment: Y para poner la ropa lavada en la secadora, es *pasa la ropa a la secadora*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente, es ***tender la colada***:

- Tienes artículos en Internet sobre [tender la colada](https://www.hogarmania.com/hogar/limpieza-orden/ropa-tejidos/201005/tender-colada-6659.html).
- Tienes mi experiencia que dice que aquí en Andalucía la usamos bastante.
- Tienes casos en el CORDE (negritas mías):

  > *[...] donde hay mujeres regando plantas que crecen en desfondados cajones de madera y muchachas que **tienden la colada** con una pinza y una canción entre los dientes.*
  >
  > Juan Marsé, "Últimas tardes con Teresa", 1966 (España).
- Incluso casos bastante añejos:

  > *[...] todavía tuve fortuna que no entraron en el patio adonde estaba toda **la colada tendida** y dos cajas de las de platillas adonde tenían todas las colchas y mantas de las camas para el invierno [...].*
  >
  > Raimundo de Lantery, "Memorias", 1705 (España).

Eso sí, es posible que *colada* sea un término que solo se use en España, dado que todos los casos que encuentro son de aquí. Basta con ver las entradas para *colada* en el *Diccionario de americanismos*:

> **[colada](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=colada)**.
>   1. f. *Co, Ec.* Alimento que se prepara disolviendo harina de maíz en agua o leche caliente con azúcar o sal y cociendo la mezcla resultante hasta que adquiera una consistencia espesa.
>   2. f. *RD, Ar, Ur.* Entrada o acceso a una fiesta o espectáculo sin haber sido invitado o sin pagar. pop.
>   3. f. *Gu.* Embrollo, trifulca.
>   4. f. *Gu.* Asunto, negocio.
>   5. f. *Cu.* Preparación del café.
>   6. *Ho.* Equivocación, error.
>   7. f. *PR.* chinchorro, red de pesca montada en pita.

De hecho, si buscas "colada" en el [CORPES XXI](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corpes-xxi) y restringes la búsqueda a América, ninguno de los resultados hace referencia a la definición de "ropa lavada". Por lo que tendremos que esperar a ver qué dicen nuestros amigos del otro lado del Atlántico, aunque coincido [con walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21220/12637) en que lo más sencillo sea simplemente decir ***tender la ropa***.

Answer (score 5):

"***Tender la ropa***" o, más claramente, "***poner la ropa a secar***" son las expresiones que se usan en mi entorno. La que indicas de "***tender la colada***", aunque bastante menos, también la he oído.

Puesto que ya OP ofrece las definiciones para "colada" y "tender", no veo necesario incluirlas yo mismo. Idem para "ropa". Simplemente intento dar una referencia que pueda confirmar la solución que OP propone.

Answer (score 3):

Acá en Buenos Aires se suele utilizar "tender la ropa" o "colgar la ropa"

Comment: Exacto. Por lo visto es así en todas partes, la de "tender la ropa" es la única que había oído, y parece la más universal (y lógica).

Answer (score 0):

En Venezuela decimos "tender la ropa". El español es un  idioma muy rico y diverso, también está el caso de las pop corn (en inglés) conocidas como "palomitas de maíz" en la mayoría de los países de habla hispana, muy usadas para comer cuando se ve una película pero en Venezuela las llamamos "cotufas", una palabra que deriva de la frase "corn to fried" que estaba escrita en los empaques del maíz utilizado para prepar

Comment: Interesante, no entiendo el porqué de añadir un enlace...

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, Natucha.